# Is it feasible to visit the Yarra Valley by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, australia, melbourne

What public transport options are there for getting to the Yarra Valley from Melbourne, and do they stop at tourist sites or are they just local services?  It looks like there's no train access to the Yarra Valley at the least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible, yes.  Feasible, only barely.  Yarra Valley is fundamentally car country and not having your own wheels handicaps you pretty badly; you can use the buses to get to the towns, but the whole point of visiting Yarra (for most visitors, anyway) is to tour the wineries, most of which are nowhere near a bus stop.

There is, however, one good way to both use public transport and get your own wheels: **rent a bike**!  The fabulous [Lilydale-Warburton Rail Trail](http://www.yarraranges.vic.gov.au/things_to_do/lilydale_to_warburton_rail_trail) starts from train terminus Lilydale, where you can rent a bike, and continues for 39 kilometers across the valley to Warburton, passing lots of wineries along the way, some directly off the trail, most a short detour away.  Since it's a former train line, it's completely separated from road traffic, and it's nice, easy ride since the hills were leveled out for the trains.  And there are many B&Bs etc if you want to stay overnight.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch a train out to Lilydale which is the end of the line and on the edge of the Yarra Valley. From there, you're reliant on public buses. [Bus #927](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/route/view/927) will take you to Healesville Sanctuary which is the biggest tourist attraction in the Yarra Valley.

Alternatively, there is also a bus that runs [all the way from the city](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/route/view/1935) out to Healesville, but it only goes a couple of times per day.

If you are wanting to visit wineries, your best option is to get on a tour bus that takes you around to a few different ones.